# Adapter for a PartialFunction

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I am trying to come up with a combinator that would allow me do something like this:

```
 def pfAdapter(pf: PartialFunction[String, String]): PartialFunction[(String,String), String]) = { 
   case (a,b) if(pf.isDefinedAt(a)) => pf(a)
 }
```

Basically, I have a `Map[String, String]`, and want to use it as a `PartialFunction` that takes two parameters - ignore the second element, and use the first one as a key.

The approach above works, but I don't like the fact that `pf` essentially gets evaluated twice (there may be no way around that), and that it's not "elegant" ... I was wondering if there is some kind of a combinator I don't know about that would let me do something like `{ _._1 } andThen pf`. This last attempt doesn't work, obviously, because the result of it is always defined, and will simply fail on non-existent keys, I am just using it as an illustration of how the solution I am looking for would ideally look.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: So you're OK with an exception if the key doesn't exist? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I want a PartialFunction, that is defined on tuples, having their first element present as a key in map. No exceptions :)

Comment: Then how is it partial? What is the desired outcome when the first element is not present?

Comment: Like any partial function: if you call it with a value outside of its domain, you get an exception. So, in that sense, yes, I am ok with it :). The idea, however us for it to never be called on such values, because it would have `lift`, `isDefinedAt`, `orElse`, etc. defined properly.

Comment: Ah ha! So, isn't `if(pf.isDefinedAt(a)) => pf(a)` exactly the same as `=> pf(a)`? Both will work if the pf is defined at a, and give an exception if not

Comment: The behavior is the same when you do `outerFunction(badKey -> unusedX)`, yes, but it is different for `outerFunction.isDefinedAt(badKey -> unusedX)` or, for example, for `outerFunction orElse  getDefault` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function itself (`pf.apply`) is not really evaluated twice, but its `isDefinedAt` *is* evaluated twice for successful matches with your definition. And that means evaluating twice `unapply`-s and guards in the initial `PartialFunction` `pf`.

By the way there is a combinator in Scalaz that does a similar thing: `pf.first.andThen(_._1)`, but it is basically equivalent to your definition.

You can write a small test, to see if `pf.isDefinedAt` is evaluated twice and run it with several possible implementations of `pfAdapter`:

```
object Unapply {
  def unapply(s: String): Boolean = {
    println(s"unapplying on $s")
    s == "1"
  }
}

val m = Map("1" -> 1, "2" -> 2)
def pf: PartialFunction[String, String] = {
  case Unapply() => "11"
}

def pfAdapter1[A, B, T](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): PartialFunction[(A, T), B] =
  Function.unlift((t: (A, T)) => pf.lift(t._1))

def pfAdapter2[A, B, T](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): PartialFunction[(A, T), B] =
  new PartialFunction[(A, T), B] {
    def isDefinedAt(arg: (A, T)) = pf.isDefinedAt(arg._1)
    def apply(arg: (A, T)) = pf(arg._1)
  }

def pfAdapter3[A, B, T](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): PartialFunction[(A, T), B] = {
  case (a,b) if pf.isDefinedAt(a) => pf(a)
}

def pfAdapter4[A, B, T](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): PartialFunction[(A, T), B] = {
  import scalaz.Scalaz._
  pf.first.andThen(_._1)
}

println(m collect pfAdapter1(pf))
println(m collect pfAdapter2(pf))
println(m collect pfAdapter3(pf))
println(m collect pfAdapter4(pf))
```

And the result of executing this code is as follows:

```
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 2
List(11)
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 2
List(11)
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 2
List(11)
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 1
unapplying on 2
List(11)
```

So the first implementation of `pfAdapter`: `Function.unlift((t: (A, T)) => pf.lift(t._1))` actually *does* avoid evaluating `isDefinedAt` twice.

This works, because `Map.collect` is implemented with `PartialFunction.applyOrElse`, and the documentation for `applyOrElse` states, that:

> For all partial function literals the compiler generates an
>   applyOrElse implementation which avoids double evaluation of pattern
>   matchers and guards. This makes applyOrElse the basis for the
>   efficient implementation for many operations and scenarios, such as:
>
> ...
>
> - lift and unlift do not evaluate source functions twice on each invocation

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the `.unlift`, I did not know about it.